# jQuery .on(), .live(), and .click() all only work one time through

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried all three and each of them only works one time through, and I have to refresh to get it to work again. Heres my code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#notificationTB').on('click', function(){
        document.getElementById('notificationTB').src='img/notifC.png';
        $('#notifBox').css('display', 'block');

        $(this).on('click', function(){
            document.getElementById('notificationTB').src='img/notif.png';
            $('#notifBox').css('display', 'none');
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: are you doing this inside of a for loop? Or are you adding the dynamic html after binding the on click events? If so instead of this: $('#notificationTB').on('click', function(){, if you do $(document).on('click', '#notificationTB', function(){, that should add the click event for every #notificationTB object even if they are added after adding dynamic html.

Comment: Check your browser console. Do you see any errors? Also, you probably don't want to define that onclick inside another onclick.

Comment: Still only works one time through and no I have no errors, and I have to define it inside of that because the first click needs to happen before the second one can happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to toggle between two states. How you're doing it isn't very good, since it's usually poor form to define an element's click handler in it's own click handler, especially since in this case the old one isn't removed. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#notificationTB').on('click', function(){
        var self = $(this); //refers to this element - $('#notificationTB')

        if(self.attr("src") == "img/notif.png"){
            self.attr("src", "img/notifC.png");
            $('#notifBox').css('display', 'block'); //.show() or .hide() will also do this
        } else {
            self.attr("src", "img/notif.png");
            $('#notifBox').css('display', 'none');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: that works perfectly, so instead of relying on events to happen to do another event, use conditional statements in the future if im understanding correctly?

Comment: When toggling the same element through the same event, yes.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `.toggle()` to switch between `display: block` and `display: none`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#notificationTB').on('click', function(){
        $('#notificationTB').attr('src',function(i,str) {
            return (str=='img/notifC.png') ? 'img/notif.png' : 'img/notifC.png';
        });
        $('#notifBox').toggle();
    });
});
```

or better yet:

```
$(document).on('click', '#notificationTB', function(){
        $(this).attr('src',function(i,str) {
            return (str=='img/notifC.png') ? 'img/notif.png' : 'img/notifC.png';
        });
        $('#notifBox').toggle();
    });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex--attr

Comment: I have to also change the img src from 'img/notif' to 'img/notifC' aswell.

Comment: saw that late - fixed now.

Comment: or simply `this.src = (this.src=='img/notifC.png') ? 'img/notif.png' : 'img/notifC.png';`

Comment: @KevinB True -- although if it were me, I'd embed the alternate src in the `<img>` using a `data-` attribute for maximum flexibility, then switch them using JavaScript.

Comment: One thing about this is it isn't necessarily syncing the state of the notification box and the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '#notificationTB', function(){
        document.getElementById('notificationTB').src='img/notifC.png';
        $('#notifBox').css('display', 'block');

        $(this).on('click', function(){
            document.getElementById('notificationTB').src='img/notif.png';
            $('#notifBox').css('display', 'none');
        });
    });
});
```

alternatively you could likely use this instead

```
$(document).on('click', '#notificationTB', function(){
    $('#notificationTB').attr('src','img/notifC.png');
    $('#notifBox').css('display', 'block');
    $(this).on('click', function(){
        $('#notificationTB').attr('src','img/notif.png');
        $('#notifBox').css('display', 'none');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using getElementById when you have jQuery?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#notificationTB').on('click', function(){
        var $box = $('#notifBox'), $this = $(this);
        $box.toggle();      
        if($box.is(":visible")){
            $this.attr('src','img/notifC.png');
        }else{
            $this.attr('src','img/notif.png');
        }       
    });
});
```